# Excel output of SPSS Modeler

Tags: neural-network, spss-modeler

In using the [dataset SP500W90](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/DAAG/SP500W90.csv) for Artificial Neural Network in SPSS Modeler, I have a simple stream below.

It generate a result of accuracy 90.9%.

[image]

I want to output the predicted values side by side with the existing “closing”, however it doesn’t create an Excel file.

Here’s the setting in the Excel node.

[image]

How can I output the prediction in Excel file (side by side with the original “closing”)? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images are not being shown for me. But, in order to export to Excel, you have to use a **Type node** in front of the **Export Excel node**. You have to set all type of variables inside the Type Node and then export. And if you want to choose the order of appearence of the variables in the Excel file, use the **Field Reorder node** before the Export Node.

Check the references from IBM for more details:

[Ref 1 - Field Reorder Node](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS3RA7_15.0.0/com.ibm.spss.modeler.help/reorder_reordertab.htm)

[Ref 2 - Type Node](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS3RA7_15.0.0/com.ibm.spss.modeler.help/type_settingstab.htm)

Hope to have been helpful!

Answer (score 1):

1. I would swap the Partition and Type node places. Partition field needs to be instantiated.
2. Your diamond node (the algorithm) has to be connected to the data flow, that is the Partition node in your case.
3. Put a Type node before extracting to Excel. You may need to rename the field starting with $ through a Filter node.
4. You could also do much painless job extracting to csv / flat file. :)